Beginner problem with adding two binary strings to get a binary string result on leetcode
I'm stuck on this problem on leetcode where you get 2 strings with binary values and you have to return their sum as a binary string. However, some test cases like a='11' b='1' do not return the correct answer.
class Solution(object):
    def addBinary(self, a, b):
        adecimal=0
        bdecimal=0
        powera=0
        powerb=0
        for x in a[::-1]:
            if x=='1':
                adecimal+=2**powera
            powera+=1
        for i in b[::-1]:
            if i=='1':
                bdecimal+=2**powerb
            powerb+=1
        resultdecimal=adecimal+bdecimal
        powerdecimal=0
        resultstring=''
        while resultdecimal>=2**powerdecimal:
            powerdecimal+=1
        while resultdecimal!=0:
            if resultdecimal>=2**powerdecimal:
                resultdecimal-=2**powerdecimal
                powerdecimal-=1
                resultstring+='1'
            else:
                powerdecimal-=1
                resultstring+='0'
        resultstring=resultstring[::-1]
        
        return resultstring

For the example a='11' b='1', it returns '10' while it should return '100'. chatGPT said it had something to do with how I calculate the powerdecimal but all of his solutions didn't work.

Please provide a [mcve], exactly how to call this. Also, include both expected and actual output. Hard-code the input into your program for demonstration purposes. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: I'm halfway sure that using a debugger to step through the code would help you, too, so try to find a video tutorial for your IDE.

Surely you can just convert the binary values to integers, add them, and convert the result back to binary... your code could be something like return bin(int(a, 2) + int(b, 2)).removeprefix("0b")

@kindall I thought the same thing, but due to the nature of this being leetcode I imagine a solution like this isn't detailed enough for an interview context to show understanding. In practice you do that of course though.

Solution to your leetcode version
Adjust powerdecimal to start from the highest valid power (currently one too high)
Change this:
while resultdecimal >= 2 ** powerdecimal:
    powerdecimal += 1

To this:
while resultdecimal >= 2 ** powerdecimal:
    powerdecimal += 1
powerdecimal -= 1

Suggested Solution
class Solution(object):
    def addBinary(self, a, b):
        return bin(int(a, 2) + int(b, 2))[2:]

How it works. Converts binary strings to decimal (integers). Performs decimal addition. Then converts back to binary string and strips '0b' prefix using [2:]

You can also use python built-in methods for converting between base-n systems. To convert a string containing number into an int you can use int() constructor. It takes base as an optional parameter. To convert int back to binary string you can use bin() function.
a = "111"
b = "101"

c = int(a, base=2) + int(b, base=2)

print(bin(c))

Concerning the performance of the solution for long string values, do remember that conversion from binary string to int is done in linear time. Furthermore, conversions are primarily functions written in C. Addition itself is not computationally expensive either. Therefore, even though we're dealing with large numbers, the entire process - converting to int, performing addition, and converting back to string - maintains linear time complexity.
As regards algorithm that processes inputs as strings, it is also linear, so both conventions are equally good.

The challenge on Leetcode says that a and b can be up to 10,000 digits. What will the performance of this be like with such huge inputs, compared to a solution that just processes the inputs as strings?

No need for base= in your int conversions, the second parameter is automatically interpreted as the base.

You're ending your loop too early:
while resultdecimal!=0:

As soon as resultdecimal only consists of trailing zeros, it stops.  The example you use was 100 so the last 0 gets dropped.
